# How do you access a child element in Actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have the following Flash structure.

```
Main Timeline
---test_menu (Movie Clip)
------test_menu_sub (Movie Clip)
---------submenu_item (Button)
```

On Main Timeline (2nd frame), I added this code:

```
test_menu.test_menu_sub.submenu_item.onPress = function () {
     trace("clicked");
}
```

However, this doesn't work. How do you access a child element or movie clip in actionscript 2? Please see the following files for reference.

- FLA: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92494048/test.fla
- SWF: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92494048/test.swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is known issue, especially when creating As2 banners. In As2 you can not have a button event like onPress work on a movie clip as well as for a movie clip nested within it.

There is very good explanation about buttons in As2 here: 
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/buttoncapturing/

However I decided to solve this fully. Here is your modified source file using functionality from the article above: 
http://www.baruckis.com/my-files/stackoverflow/11542639/test.fla

I hope it will help! ;)